# How to calculate rotation of arrow to point along a vector in 3D?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors, 3d

I have a 3D vector Starting at some point A and ending at some point B. I have an arrow sitting at point A. I need to rotate the arrow such that it is pointing along the vector from point A to point B. The arrow starts pointing along the y axis (take a look at the image to see this better). I'm really not much of a mathematician and I'm struggling with this. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Vector AB in the 3D space]

Comment: you need to calculate two things: 1) normal vector with cross product 2) angle between vectors.

Comment: Is the normal vector the vector perpendicular to my vector? I might need a little more hand holding haha

Comment: A walk-through answer will be a bit hairy. If you have specific numbers, it will be far easier.

Comment: Things to do: **1)** Calculate the axis of rotation: vector product of "arrow" and AB. **2)** Calculate the angle of rotation, by $|a x b| = |a||b|sin\theta$. **3)** Construct the 3x3 matrix of rotation **4)** multiply this matrix with the "arrow". The result is a vector starting at point A.

Comment: @AlexS Unfortunately, its a general issue I need to deal with. I'm working on a 3D visualization and I actually have many vectors. I need to rotate an arrow for all of these, but the rotation will be different for most of the vectors. Totally understand if its too much to explain. Maybe there is a general case? If I understand the idea I might be able to tackle the edge cases myself.

Comment: @Ripi2 That sounds promising. I'll try it out!

Comment: The idea is that a 3D rotation around an axis that goes through the origin can be expressed by a matrix that uses the axis and the angle. Then the product M·P rotates P around that axis. If the axis doesn't pass though origin then first move it all to $(0,0,0)$ (the translate vector is the point A), then rotate, then move back to A.

Answer (score 1):

So you need three things:

1. normal vector using cross product
2. angle between vectors
3. a matrix that rotates the arrow

So the first step is simply cross product.
2nd step is angle between vectors using
$$ a=\frac{acos(a_1 \cdot a_2)}{len(a_1)*len(a_2)} $$, where $len(a_0) = \sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2}$

3rd step is a matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(a)+(1-cos(a))*x^2 & (1-cos(a))*x*y-sin(a)*z & (1-cos(a))*x*z+sin(a)*y & 0 \\
(1-cos(a))*y*x+sin(a)*z & cos(a)+(1-cos(a))*y^2 & (1-cos(a))*y*z-sin(a)*x & 0 \\
(1-cos(a))*z*x-sin(a)*y & (1-cos(a))*z*y+sin(a)*x & cos(a)+(1-cos(a))*z^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
There $(x,y,z) = normalize(cross(a_1,a_2))$.

Note that you can only apply the matrix when the vectors start from origo, so you need translate the system from point A to origo using standard translate matrix. and then after applying the matrix, translate it back to point A.

Comment: This looks great! I'll try it out and accept the answer if it works

Comment: Are a1 and a2 points A and B? If so, isn't len(a1) = 0 if I translate the vector to the origin?

Comment: no, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the vectors, i.e. B-A and C-A.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call your first vector--the one from A to B-- $\vec x=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3\rangle$. Let us call the other vector $\vec y=\langle y_1,y_2,y_3\rangle$. We follow these steps:

1. **Find the angle between $\vec x$ and $\vec y$.** To calculate the angle between vectors, use the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product). The dot product has the property that $\vec x\cdot\vec y=\Vert \vec x\Vert \Vert \vec y\Vert\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors. Translated to vector components, this means $$x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3=\sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2)}\cos\theta.$$ This allows you to calculate the angle $$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3}{\sqrt{(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)(y_1^2+y_2^2+y_3^2)}}\right).$$
2. **Find the direction of the axis of rotation.** The axis of rotation is perpendicular to both of the vectors. To find a vector in that direction, use the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). The cross product is $\vec x\times\vec y=\langle x_2y_3-x_3y_2,x_3y_1-x_1y_3,x_1y_2-x_2y_1\rangle$. Let $z_1=x_2y_3-x_3y_2$, $z_2=x_3y_1-x_1y_3$, and $z_3=x_1y_2-x_2y_1$, with $\vec z=\vec x\times\vec y=\langle z_1,z_2,z_3\rangle.$ The next step will be easier if the vector pointing in the direction of the axis of rotation has length one. To this end, let $$\vec w=\langle\vec w_1,w_2,w_3\rangle=\left\langle \frac{z_1}{\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}},\frac{z_2}{\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}},\frac{z_3}{\sqrt{z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2}}\right\rangle.$$ $\vec w$ is also perpendicular to both $\vec x$ and $\vec y$, but has length $1$.
3. **Use Rodrigues' Formula.** Rodrigues' Formula tells us the components of the rotated vector based on $\vec w$ and $\theta$, and it uses the dot product and cross product again. It is: \begin{align*}\text{rotated vector}&=\vec y \cos\theta+(\vec w\times \vec y)\sin\theta+\vec w(\vec w\cdot\vec y)(1-\cos\theta)\\&=\langle y_1 \cos (\theta )-w_2 y_3 \sin (\theta )+w_3 y_2 \sin (\theta ),\\&w_1 y_3 \sin (\theta )-w_3 y_1 \sin (\theta )+y_2 \cos (\theta ),\\&-w_1 y_2 \sin (\theta )+w_2 y_1 \sin (\theta )+y_3 \cos (\theta )\rangle.\end{align*}

It is pretty complicated, but that is the simplest way to do it.

Edit: since $\vec w$ is perpendicular to $\vec y$, their dot product is zero, and so the result of Rodrigues' Formula is simpler. I changed it above.

Comment: Sorry, where does the vector y come from?

Comment: $y$ is your arrow, the one you need to rotate.

Comment: Ahh right sorry that make sense

Comment: Since the vector x does not start at the origin, what values do I use for x1, x2, x3? B minus A?